# jQuery loader doesn't work properly in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, firefox, safari

I want to show loader on href click. Here is my code, which works properly, except Safari:

```
setTimeout(function(){
 $.loader({className:'blue-with-image-2',content:''});
},200);
```

it is linked to `a href's onclick` event, just a fragment to make it clear:

```
<a class="btn upload-btn" href="#" onclick=" setTimeout(function(){
     $.loader({className:'blue-with-image-2',content:''});
    },200);");
```

here is blue-with-image-2 css part(it's standard):

```
#jquery-loader.blue-with-image-2{border:0;padding-top:35px;background-color:transparent;text-align:center;background-image:url(/common/img/ajax-loader.gif);background-position:center center;background-repeat:no-repeat}
```

Comment: show your CSS `blue-with-image-2` class.

Comment: @WisdmLabs see updates in question